# How to make python script better and object oriented?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am starting my adventure with Python and object oriented programming.

I wrote a script for salting and hashing password. My main goal is practice with OOP, not cryptography. I know there is no error handling.

Wonder how improve my code it and make more object oriented. It would be nice if someone more experienced can take a look and give me some advice how to make it better. Any help for newbie would be great!

Below my code with short description and questions.

**Questions:**

I) What is a real difference between these two? With and w/o **self.X** works

```
def generate_new_salt(self, salt_ln=16):
        self.new_salt = os.urandom(salt_ln)
        print(f'new salt: {self.new_salt}')
        return self.new_salt
```

and

```
def generate_new_salt(self, salt_ln=16):
    new_salt = os.urandom(salt_ln)
    print(f'new salt: {new_salt}')
    return new_salt
```

II) I have problem with passing default value of salt length (salt_ln = 16). For me it does not look nice when it is replicated in every method. Is there any way to do it more global?

III)

**Description:**

The script is not really useful in real life.

1st part:

Hash and salt password and next encode to base64 with added salt (needed for future comparing hashes). Algorithm: base64( SHA256(password + salt) + salt)
Salt is X random bytes where X can be specify but by default it is 16.

2nd part (some kind of authorization):

Compare input hash (e.x. from database) with new created hash from input plain password.
New salt is created from  salt taken from input hash.

**Code:**

```py
    import base64
    import hashlib
    import os


    class Hashing(object):

        # base64( SHA256(password + salt) + salt)

        # generate new salt (default 16 bytes)
        def generate_new_salt(self, salt_ln=16):

            self.new_salt = os.urandom(salt_ln)

            print(f'new salt: {self.new_salt}')

            return self.new_salt

        # get salt from hash
        def get_old_salt(self, input_hash, salt_ln=16):

            self.old_salt = base64.b64decode(input_hash)[-salt_ln:]

            print(f'old salt: {self.old_salt}')

            return self.old_salt

        # compute hash using parameters
        def compute_hash(self, password, salt):

            self.salt = salt
            self.enc_password = password.encode()

            # hashing SHA256(password + salt)
            hash_object = hashlib.sha256(self.enc_password + salt)

            # add salt to hash and encode to base64
            hash_b64 = base64.b64encode(hash_object.digest() + salt)

            print(f'new_hash: {hash_b64}')
            return hash_b64

        # create hash from new or old salt
        def create_hash(self, password, salt_ln=16,old_salt=None):

            if old_salt:    #if old salt then use it
                self.salt = old_salt
            else:           #else generate new salt
                self.salt = Hashing().generate_new_salt(salt_ln)


            hash = Hashing().compute_hash(password, self.salt)

            return hash

        # compare input hash with created using salt get from input
        def compare_hashes(self, password, old_hash, salt_ln=16):

            self.enc_password = password.encode()

            #get salt from input hash
            self.old_salt = Hashing().get_old_salt(old_hash, salt_ln)

            #recreat input hash
            re_hash = Hashing().create_hash(password,salt_ln, self.old_salt)

            print(f'Compare: old_hash: {old_hash}')
            print(f'Compare: new_hash: {re_hash}')

            #compare
            if re_hash.decode() == old_hash.decode():
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

```
#code below is just for testing

NewSalt = Hashing().generate_new_salt()

Hash = Hashing().create_hash('pass')

OldSalt = Hashing().get_old_salt(Hash)

CompareHash = Hashing().compare_hashes('pass', Hash)

if CompareHash:
    print('HASHES THE SAME')
else:
    print('NOT THE SAME')

print(CompareHash)
```

Comment: *"I wrote a script for salting and hashing password. Wonder how improve it and make more object oriented. It would be nice if someone more experienced can take a look and give me some advice how to make it more kosher. Any help for newbie would be great!"* Sounds like a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com - that's the place to ask about style issues and general advice for improving code.

Comment: @kaya3 I didn't know about this place. I will move this question there.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a default value in the class's `__init__` method, then you can write your method to accept a value or use the class's default value

```py
class Hashing(object):
    def __init__(self, salt_ln):
        self.default_salt_ln = salt_ln

    # base64( SHA256(password + salt) + salt)

    # generate new salt (default 16 bytes)
    def generate_new_salt(self, salt_ln=None):
        salt_ln = salt_ln or self.default_salt_ln
        self.new_salt = os.urandom(salt_ln)

        print(f'new salt: {self.new_salt}')

        return self.new_salt
```

Now you can call your method either way:

```py
Hashing(16).generate_new_salt()

Hashing(16).generate_new_salt(salt_ln=10)
```